# String comparison with StartsWith or Substring does not work

Tags: c#, .net

I need to find what attachment i downloaded from email message, but im not able to compare the attachment filename with string, what im doing wrong ? Script should return "in in" but it returns "out out"

```
FileAttachment fileAttachment = item.Attachments[0] as FileAttachment;

Console.WriteLine(fileAttachment.Name);

if (fileAttachment.FileName.StartsWith("OpenOrders")) {
    Console.WriteLine("in"); 
} 
else { 
    Console.WriteLine("out"); 
}

if (fileAttachment.FileName.Substring(0, 10) == "OpenOrders") { 
    Console.WriteLine("in"); 
} else { 
    Console.WriteLine("out"); 
}
```

Output:

```
OpenOrders some text with spaces.xlsx
out
out
```

Comment: What is the value of `fileAttachment.FileName`? Be aware, `StartsWith(string)` method does case-sensitive and culture-sensitive comparison.

Comment: `fileAttachment.FileName` is not the same as `fileAttachment.Name`

Comment: Probably the full path.

Comment: ah ohmygo thank you, im so blind, unbelieveable !!
fileAtachment.Name work!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are outputting `fileAttachment.Name` but using `fileAttachment.FileName` in the `StartsWith`. Use the correct version and it should work.

```
FileAttachment fileAttachment = item.Attachments[0] as FileAttachment;

Console.WriteLine(fileAttachment.Name);

if (fileAttachment.Name.StartsWith("OpenOrders")) {
    Console.WriteLine("in"); 
} 
else { 
    Console.WriteLine("out"); 
}

if (fileAttachment.Name.Substring(0, 10) == "OpenOrders") { 
    Console.WriteLine("in"); 
} else { 
    Console.WriteLine("out"); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. Im so blind that i even did not realized i was using diferent method :p

Answer (score 2):

You're outputting the `Name` property:

```
Console.WriteLine(fileAttachment.Name);
```

But your `StartsWith` and `Substring` calls are against the`FileName` property. I suspect you'll find that `Name` is returning something different to `FileName`.